# react-native-force is not working with where clause

Tags: mobilesdk

I am using the react-native-force library and getting an error when I add **where** clause in SQL.

My code:

let sql = `SELECT Id FROM Account where Id = '0014P00002l5S9EQAU'`;

```
 net.query (sql,
   (response) => {
     console.log ("Search accounts ->", response.records.length);
   }, (error) => {
     console.log ("error ->", error)
   }
 );
```

Error: SFNetReactBridge.sendRequest failed: {"error": "unsupported URL", "message": "sendRequest failed"}